# Create a custom JavaScript method for DOM elements

Tags: javascript

Elements in this environment are nested inside containers - let's call them widgets.  Given any element, I want to find its containing widget using a custom method called `parentWidget`.  The widget can always be identified by the class name "widget".  I want this to behave exactly like `parentElement`, except that it might be several levels deep, so it should use the JavaScript method `.closest()` to traverse up the DOM tree.

I wrote this, but I don't like that I need to use parenthesis to execute the function:

```
Element.prototype.parentWidget = function() {
    return this.closest('.widget');
}
```

```js
// Custom method
Element.prototype.parentWidget = function() {
    return this.closest('.widget');
}

// Works
function test(el) {
  var widget = el.parentWidget();
  var result = document.getElementById("w1");
  result.firstChild.innerText = widget;
}

/* This is a silly example to illustrate what I'm 
 * trying to achieve, except that I don't want to 
 * require parenthesis.  Instead, I want this to 
 * seem like a native method like, 'parentNode' or 
 * 'firstChild'
 *
 * How can I rewrite this?
*/
```

```css
:root {
    --btn1: hsl(206, 100%, 52%);
    --btn2: hsl(206, 100%, 40%);
}

.widget {
  display: block;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 150px;
}

.widget > div {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.style-1 button {
    color: white;
    background-color: var(--btn1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: background .25s;
}

.style-1 button:not([disabled]):hover {
    background-color: var(--btn2);
}

.full {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="w1"><span>Click to test</span></div>
<div class="widget">
  <div class="style-1">
    <button type="button" class="full" onclick="test(this)">Try Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

At some point, I may want to concatenate other methods, so I won't want to use parenthesis (e.g., `el.parentWidget.firstChild`, etc.)

Comment: Make a getter: `Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'parentWidget', {get: function() {return this.closest('.widget');}, enumerable: true});`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you Teemu!

Comment: [Please don't do that](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom)